# не могу извлечь текст из простого api

Tags: python, telegram-bot

хотел сделать так, чтобы бот присылал рандомную аниме цитату, но совершенно не понимаю как работать с апи.
получилось реализовать рандомную картинку, но в этом случае я просто не понимаю.

```
import requests
import telebot
import bs4  # BeautifulSoup4
from telebot import types
from io import BytesIO

def get_quote():

    anime = ''
    character = ''
    quote = ''

    req = requests.get('https://animechan.vercel.app/api/random')
    if req.status_code == 200:
        r_json = req.json()
        anime = r_json["anime"]
        # url.split("/")[-1]
    return anime
```

Ошибка из-за неверного оформления кода, но я совершенно не смыслю, поэтому и исправить не могу

> TypeError: get_quote() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Comment: А где вызов самой функции? `get_quote`

Comment: @turkindv
Вызов функции происходит в меню бота

`elif ms_text == "Прислать цитату":`
`get_quote(chat_id)`

Comment: ну вот уберите `chat_id`, сделайте просто `get_quote()`, ваша функция не принимает аргументов, а тут вы пытаетесь передать один аргумент, о чем и говорится в ошибке, судя по коду, `chat_id` не используется в функции, поэтому просто выкиньте его и все

Comment: все норм, я все сделал, очень глупый вопрос был))